# Error:External resource http://www.example.com/ is not registered

Tags: xml, xsd

I am reading book "Java XML and JSON" by Apress. I created file `recipe.xml` but not valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<recipe xmlns="http://www.tutortutor.ca/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tutortutor.ca/schemas recipe.xsd">
    <title>Grilled Cheese Sandwich</title>
    <ingredients>
        <ingredient qty="2">bread slice</ingredient>
        <ingredient>cheese slice</ingredient>
        <ingredient qty="2">margarine pat</ingredient>
    </ingredients>
    <instructions>
        Place frying pan on element and select medium heat. For each bread
        slice, smear one pat of margarine on one side of bread slice. Place
        cheese slice between bread slices with margarine-smeared sides away
        from the cheese. Place sandwich in frying pan with one
        margarine-smeared side in contact with pan. Fry for a couple of
        minutes and flip. Fry other side for a minute and serve.
    </instructions>
</recipe>
```

**recipe.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="instructions" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="qty" type="xs:unsignedInt" default="1"/>
    <xs:element name="recipe">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="title"/>
                <xs:element ref="ingredients"/>
                <xs:element ref="instructions"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ingredients">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ingredients" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ingredient">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute ref="qty"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

[image]
How I make my xml file become valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make the following changes:**

1. Remove `xmlns="http://www.tutortutor.ca/"` from the root element because the XSD has no such `targetNamespace`.
2. Change

   ```
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tutortutor.ca/schemas recipe.xsd"
   ```

   to

   ```
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="recipe.xsd"
   ```
3. Fix the typo in the XSD:

   ```
   <xs:element ref="ingredients" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <xs:element ref="ingredient" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   ```

**Then your XML will be valid against your XSD, as requested.**